# Negative text indent, translate on hover bug (firefox)

Tags: css, firefox, hover, transform, text-indent

I'm experiencing a firefox specific bug with a simple menu I've built

It's a ul-list that has an on-hover effect for the list items, the list items have `transform:translateX(12px)` applied on hover, and the text links have a negative indent applied at all times, the combination of the two create a Firefox specific bug where part of the text disappears on hover during its animation, looks like its basically being hidden by its own padding because of the negative value.

Here is a JS Fiddle as well as the code, am I missing -moz- css?

https://jsfiddle.net/CultureInspired/9435v0vy/1/

```
<ul class="menu_desktop">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Press</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu_desktop {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 80px;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu_desktop li {
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-indent: -.8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    display: table;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.menu_desktop li:hover {
    transform: translateX(12px);
}

.menu_desktop a {
    color: #000;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: It's fine to me on firefox.

Comment: Really?? The issue happens for me in the fiddle and on my site, the first two letters or so of every word goes invisible for about 1 second. Could it be my hardware or OS?

Comment: do you really need the `text-indent` on the `li`?

Comment: I don't know what could be the problem. [Here's what](https://vid.me/jcrg) I see.

Comment: Oh strange, yep works perfect in your example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same issue with firefox 49.0.2, it seems like a bug.

You can solve this by using `margin-left: 12px;` instead of the `transform` you are currently using.

Here is the fix (works in firefox, chrome & ie):

```css
body {
  background: lightgray;
}
.menu_desktop {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 80px;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu_desktop li {
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-indent: -.8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    display: table;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.menu_desktop li:hover {
    margin-left: 12px;
}

.menu_desktop a {
    color: #000;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu_desktop">
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Press</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks that's a good workaround, hopefully they'll fix this sooner than later!

Comment: Did you open a bug-report regarding this issue? If they will not know about it I guess they will not be able to fix it :)